# How to convert MS SQL tables to DynamoDB tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, amazon-dynamodb, database-migration

I am new to Amazon DynamoDB and I have eight(8) MS SQL tables that I want to migrate to DynamoDB.

What process should I use for converting and migrating the database schema and data?

Comment: Generally speaking converting tables designed for a relational database system into ones suitable to a NoSQL based system requires redesigning aspects of the system through denormalization (at the very least) which is not well suited to automated conversion.

Comment: @JaredHatfield any good reference to learn how to do this ?

Comment: May be helpful to take a look at: https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/migration-best-practices-rdbms-to-dynamodb.pdf

Comment: @JohnnyWu that is a great resource please post it as answer to give you credit. Thanks

Comment: AWS posts lots of good videos on their YoutTube channel, I'd recommend checking those out: https://www.youtube.com/user/AmazonWebServices

Comment: @JaredHatfield thanks alot if you post an answer with an specific link I would give you credit/points thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same problem a year back when I started migrating the app from SQL to DynamoDB. I am not sure if there are automated tools, but I can share what we had done for migration:

1. Check if your existing data types can be mapped/need to change in DynamoDB. You can merge some of the table which requires less updates into single item with `List` and `Map` types or use a `Set` if required.
2. The most important thing is to check all your existing queries. This will be the core information you will need when you will design DynamoDB tables.
3. Make sure you distribute Hash keys properly.
4. Use GSI and LSI for searching and sorting purposes (project only those attributes that will be needed; this will save money).

Some points that will save some money:

1. If your tables are read-heavy, try using some caching mechanism, otherwise be ready to increase throughput of the tables.
2. If your table is write-heavy, then implement a queuing mechanism, such as SQS.
3. Keep checking all of your important tables status in Management console. They have provided different matrices that will help you in managing the throughput of the tables.

I have written a [blog](http://blog.cloudthat.in/migration-from-relational-database-to-nosql-database/) which include all the challenges faced while moving from relational database to NoSQL database